# Is there any way to implement a trait with the same struct of different generic constraints in Rust?

Tags: rust, traits

Suppose I have a struct `S<T>` and I want implement it to trait `Default` with different constraints of generic type `T`:

```rust
struct S<T> { ... }


impl<T> Default for S<T> 
where
    T: Ord
{
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self::new()
    }
}

impl<T> Default for S<T>
where
    T: Ord + Default
{
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self::build(T::default())
    }
}
```

However, the compiler complains:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait std::default::Default for type S<_>
```

Is there any way to compile such code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this in stable Rust.

You can use the (unstable and unsound!) `specialization` feature on nightly Rust:

```
#![feature(specialization)]

struct S<T> {
    x: Option<T>
}

impl<T> S<T> {
    fn new() -> Self { Self { x: None } }
    fn build(x: T) -> Self { Self { x: Some(x) } }
}


impl<T> Default for S<T> 
where
    T: Ord
{
    default fn default() -> Self {
        Self::new()
    }
}

impl<T> Default for S<T>
where
    T: Ord + Default
{
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self::build(T::default())
    }
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ee24c383878f7a32c53d12211b69ab4f

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems that the `specialization` still has some problem to be stable... Hope this may be resolved in the future.